# How do I increment a scss variable?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I want to style 10 divs, each 3px higher than the previous one.
But the code below makes all 10 divs 8px high.

I try to increment the `$height` variable but it's not working, why?

```
.volume-bar {
  $height: 5px;
  @for $i from 1 through 10 {
    &:nth-child($i) { height: $height;}
    height: $height + 3px;
  }
}
```

Comment: at first look I would say it need to be `$height: $height + 3px` (note the `$` at the start)

Comment: The heights are all 0px then, not sure why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues

1. the syntax on nth child is wrong.
2. If you want to increment the height assign it to the height variable.

   ```
   &:nth-child(#{$i}) { height: $height;}
   $height: $height + 3px;
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a noob at scss.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the value of a variable in a loop like that.

But what you can do is multiplication, and not change any variables. This should make it 3px higher each time through the loop. It simply multiplies the offset you want by how many times you've been through the loop and adds it to the base height.

```
height: $height + $i * 3px;
```